# C++ MFC processor thread lagging

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I am trying to debug a C++ MFC windows service application as we have found that in high-intensity environment there becomes a lag between the receipt and processing of third-party messages.

The service listens for received messages from a third-party system. On receiving a message, it passed the message to a dedicated processing thread which does all the processing of the command. The problem, as aforementioned, is that we are seeing a significant lag in the receipt and processing. We can see this because all messages include a sequence number. For example, our tracing reports that the main thread receives a message with sequence number 867 at 13:00:00, but we do not see the corresponding trace from the processing thread until 13:00:38 (this is a real-time system, so ideally it would be instantaneous).

I can also see in the tracing that, where on a normal system we would see a clean sequence of Receipt-Process-Receipt-Process-Recepit-Process etc..... on this log we have a block of 4 or 5 receipt messages, followed by 4 or 5 process messages, then another 4 or 5 receipt messages, and so on. Since these are running on different threads this surprises me, as I would expect to see the traces interspersed, even if delayed.

In the code, there is a message map like so:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProcessorThread, CWinThread)
ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_MSG_RCV, OnReceive)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The thread class looks like this (slightly abridged):

```
class CProcessorThread : public CWinThread {
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    CAMProcessingObject *obj;

    afx_msg void OnReceive(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        CString* strRecData = (CString*)wParam;
        CString& sTemp = *strRecData;

        // Various checks and filters are done here
        if (true) {
            obj->ProcessMessage(sTemp);
        }

        delete strRecData;
    }
}
```

Here is the method that initially receives the message from the third-party system (again, abridged):

```
DWORD WINAPI CAMReceiving::ThreadReceive( void * args) {
    CAMObject * camObject = (CAMObject *) args;
    char chTemp[500];
    while(true) {

        // Get the message from the socket
        memset(chTemp, 0, sizeof(chTemp));
        iRecvLen = camObject->objsocket.ReceiveData(chTemp, sizeof(chTemp) - 1);    

        CString strEventNotification = _T("");

        // Do various processing to populate the strEventNotification CString and make sure we want to process this message

        CString* strEvent = new CString(strEventNotification);
        processorThread.PostThreadMessageA(WM_MSG_RCV,(WPARAM)strEvent,0);
        continue;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

So as you may tell I didn't write this and I'm not particular familiar with the multithreading methods in C++, so my question is really is there something fundamentally wrong with this design? Or is there something I don't know that is going to cause me problems here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do some logging to check what the processing thread is doing. Maybe it is doing work and a lot of WM_MSG_RCV are waiting in the queue? Or maybe someone played around with the thread priorities?

Comment: `on this log we have a block of 4 or 5 receipt messages, followed by 4 or 5 process messages, then ...` It's hard to tell without more details, but it might be a good idea to do a `Sleep(0);` after `PostThreadMessageA` so that the processing thread gets a chance to run right away. Otherwise the loop will keep doing `PostThreadMessageA` until its time slice ends.

Comment: This would be a good time to instrument your service using [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx). Tracing can be started and stopped on demand, in live systems, providing invaluably helpful data for diagnostics and analysis.